# how to migrate with knex?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I have installed `knex` and `PostgreSQL` but when I run the command, it gives me an error.

**Command:**

```
knex migrate:latest
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null
```

Thanks for your help